# How can I recover files deleted by rm command on 14.10?

Tags: data-recovery

I rm Desktop and all the files on desktop by mistake.
Anyone of you knows how to get them back?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Ubuntu software centre and search for UNDELETE then you will find a couple of utilities which may be able to help.

I also strongly suggest setting up a backup!